# Same code with different variable name not working in PHP?

Tags: php, glob

I am using this code to list all files inside a directory which works perfectly

```
<?php 
$exclude = array("index.php","cssheadertop.php","cssheaderbottom.php");
$cssfiles = array_diff(glob("*.php"), $exclude); 
foreach ($cssfiles as $cssfile) {
$filename = "http://example.com/lessons/css/".$cssfiles[$cssfile];
outputtags($filename,true,true); 
}
?>
```

However, with this code nothing is shown on the webpage. I can't figure out why

```
<?php 
$exclude = array("index.php","htmlheadertop.php","htmlheaderbottom.php");
$htmlfiles = array_diff(glob("*.php"), $exclude); 
foreach ($htmlfiles as $htmlfile) {
$filename = "http://example.com/lessons/html/".$htmlfiles[$htmlfile];
outputtags($filename,true,true); 
}
?>
```

Comment: What does it mean `not working`?

Comment: Files are not showing up.

Comment: `.$htmlfiles[$htmlfile];` -> `$htmlfile` ? Otherwise i don't see the point to use a foreach loop

Comment: @Rizier123 That doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: Try using scandir to list directory contents.

Comment: What's the output of this `var_dump($htmlfiles)`?

Comment: @VeeeneX But it seems to be weird, he goes trough each array element and uses the value as key... (But i still don't see why it shouldn't work)

Comment: @Rizier123 what do you suggest then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502118/same-code-with-different-variable-name-not-working-in-php?noredirect=1#comment45323551_28502118 + `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` And you tell use the output + if you get errors

Comment: @Veeenex I did that it outputs the name of file correctly, let me post the values.

Comment: @SheelRanjan The first script should NOT work. The second script should NOT work. The value $htmlfiles[$htmlfile] should be null as that index should not be set. $htmlfiles should have integer keys and the values should be alphanumeric values. That is the same for $cssfiles[$cssfile]. My gut feeling is that the original script only had $cssfile, not $cssfiles[$cssfile].

Comment: @kainaw Create an answer, you're right.

Comment: @VeeeneX What's the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502118/same-code-with-different-variable-name-not-working-in-php#comment45323449_28502118 and between http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502118/same-code-with-different-variable-name-not-working-in-php#comment45323675_28502118 ? (Only that the first linked comment was posted 9minutes ago?!)

Comment: @kainaw there are 8 files in the array $cssfiles

Comment: @Rizier123 it's Friday consider that please.

Comment: @SheelRanjan I do not disagree with you that there are 8 files in the $cssfiles array. I am trying to explain that the index for those 8 files are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. You are trying to use the value of the array as an index - that will not work.

Comment: @SheelRanjan Are my comments invisible for you or do you just don't want to response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502118/same-code-with-different-variable-name-not-working-in-php#comment45323449_28502118 ?

Comment: I did not understand what that comment actually meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$exclude = array("index.php","htmlheadertop.php","htmlheaderbottom.php");
$htmlfiles = array_diff(glob("*.php"), $exclude); 
foreach ($htmlfiles as $htmlfile) {
    $filename = "http://example.com/lessons/html/".$htmlfile;
    outputtags($filename,true,true); 
}
?>
```

$htmlfiles[$htmlfile] should not be set and should not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$htmlfile` inside foreach loop instead of `$htmlfiles[$htmlfile]`, and it works with any other variable's name

```
<?php 
   $exclude = array("index.php","htmlheadertop.php","htmlheaderbottom.php");
   $htmlfiles = array_diff(glob("*.php"), $exclude); 
   foreach ($htmlfiles as $htmlfile) {
     $filename = "http://example.com/lessons/html/".$htmlfile;
     outputtags($filename,true,true); 
   }
?>
```